# C# const data performance

Tags: c#, constants

I was wondering what is the best way to specify bit-masks and group(s) of them?

```
value &= ds.mask1 | ds.mask2 | ds.mask3 | ds.mask4 | ds.mask5;
```

vs.

```
value &= ds.group1;
```

vs.

```
value &= 0x1fffffffffff;
```

Will the c# compiler optimize the first to run at same speed as the second?

```
public class ds
{
    public const ulong mask1 = 0x0000000000000fff;
    public const ulong mask2 = 0x0000000000fff000;
    public const ulong mask3 = 0x0000000fff000000;
    public const ulong mask4 = 0x00000ff000000000;
    public const ulong mask5 = 0x0000100000000000;
    public const ulong mask6 = 0x0000200000000000;
    public const ulong mask7 = 0x0000c00000000000;

    public const ulong group1 = mask1 | mask2 | mask3 | mask4 | mask5;
    public const ulong group2 = mask1 | mask6 | mask7;

    ds() {}
}
```

Are there other 'better' ways to get this sort of problem solved?

Frank

```
static void Main()
{
    ulong i, j, v;

    DateTime st, et;
    TimeSpan ts1, ts2, ts3;

    j = 100000000;

    st = DateTime.Now;
    for (v = i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        v &= ds.mask1 | ds.mask2 | ds.mask3 | ds.mask4 | ds.mask5;
        v += i;
    }

    et = DateTime.Now;
    ts1 = et - st;

    st = DateTime.Now;
    for (v = i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        v &= ds.group1;
        v += i;
    }

    et = DateTime.Now;
    ts2 = et - st;

    st = DateTime.Now;
    for (v = i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        v &= 0x1fffffffffff;
        v += i;
    }

    et = DateTime.Now;
    ts3 = et - st;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", ts1.TotalMilliseconds, ts2.TotalMilliseconds, ts3.TotalMilliseconds));
}
```

I got interesting results. Can you guys test it too?

**It seems the first is slowest (424), and second is fastest (411), while third is (414). I get consistently similar results for multiple runs.**

Comment: I seriously doubt you will  see any difference in performance, even in a tight loop. However, your conditions are wrong - instead of `if (value & 0x1fffffffffff)` it should be `if ((value & 0x1fffffffffff) == value)` (same goes to all other conditions)

Comment: Thanks. I never compiled this just porting a piece of code from 'C', and I'm completely new to c sharp optimizer tricks. I will trust to the optimizer doing its job on const data.

Comment: Even without compiler optimization I don't think there will be a noticeable difference between these 3 options.

Comment: Contants are evaluated at compile time (this is not optimization - just how constants work, so this happens always), so all your samples are completely identical.

Comment: I got interesting results.

Comment: @Frank: Worry about getting the code right first, optimize later. Furthermore, don't use `DateTime.Now` for benchmarks, use `Stopwatch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For release-mode builds, as soon as a combination of values is const (thus, consists of const expressions only) it will be computed (optimized) at compile time. So, there could be no difference you compute them by yourself or delegate it to the compiler.

Comment: Constants are always evaluated at compile time, doesn't matter if release or not (because it's not an optimization, but just definition of constant in .net)

Comment: Great. Then it's more clever than i expected from a high level language like this :)

Comment: `const` fields are also always inlined by the compiler.